# How does Django work with either instance id and instance itself?

Tags: python, django

For instance django queryset's filter takes either instance or instance_id. 
Probably django code needs `id` for Database query, and it extracts `instance_id` when it receives `instance`

Although I don't remember, there could be a scenario where django would want `instance` but receives `instance_id` .

How does django handle such cases? just do typechecking with `isinstance(something, models.Model)` and do something with it?

Comment: Luckily Django is open source and you can check how the handling works exactly.

Comment: yeah true, just being lazy.. :(